# Get-TFSChildItem does not show deleted files/folders

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to "destroy" some of the old folders in our source control and was trying to script it. I am using

```
get-tfschilditem -item $/WIP -server $tfsServer -Deleted
```

But the -Deleted switch does not seem to be making any difference. If I do

```
get-tfschilditem -item $/WIP/**MyFolder** -server $tfsServer
```

I can see the deleted folder in the source control.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong??

I am using Win8 & TFS Powertools 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Get-TfsChildItem -Item $/WIP -server $tfsServer -Deleted  | Where {$_.DeletionId -ne 0}
```

But that still doesn't return the same output as:

```
tf dir /deleted
```

It would appear to be a bug in Get-TfsChildItem.

Comment: The "where" clause worked and got me exactly what I wanted. Thanks. I guess the -Deleted parameter has a bug.